# How I can show the time in Vim Status Bar?

Tags: vim, time, statusline

This is the following code I am using

```
set statusline=\PATH:\ %r%F\ \ \ \ \LINE:\ %l/%L/%P
```

In the same statusline how I can show the time information ? Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim allows you to evaluate vim commands inside of the status line, so something like this should do the trick:

```
set statusline=\PATH:\ %r%F\ \ \ \ \LINE:\ %l/%L/%P\ TIME:\ %{strftime('%c')}
```

`%{}` executes any vim statements contained within the `{}` brackets.  If you want a different time format, read the below help topic on the `strftime` function:

```
:help strftime()
```

Also, if you need more help on the special printf style `%` characters, read this:

```
:help 'statusline'
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it so vim automatically updates the clock? For it to update I have to move my cursor/interact in some way, otherwise it remains the same.